# how to get file names from input type file in html 5 using javascript or jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

below is my simple code using HTML 5 multiple file upload. All i need is to grab all the file names not the paths below is simple javascript code

```
  function getFileNames()
        {
            var path = $('#files').val();
            console.log(' path = ' + path);
        }
```

and html form is as

```
<form action='server.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target="iframe">
                <input id="files" name='files[]' type='file' multiple>
                <input type='button' onclick="getFileNames()">
</form>
```

when i press the button the console output is as

path = Chrysanthemum.jpg

which is the first name of the file and i want the remaining names , any suggestions , comments are appreciated. 
thanks.

Comment: well after lot of work i found a nice solution.. check my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well so here i am with the solution after lot of research, in case of `input type file` the value is stored in `array` as `files` with key `name`.

```
var files = $('input#files')[0].files;
var names = "";
$.each(files,function(i, file){
    names += file.name + " ";
});
alert(names);
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/raj_er04/nze2B/1/

**pure javascript**

```
function getFileNames(){
    var files = document.getElementById("files").files;
    var names = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        names += files[i].name + " ";
    alert(names);
}
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/raj_er04/nze2B/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
    function getFileNames()
    {
       var files = document.getElementById("files").files;         
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
          console.log(' name= ' + f.name);
alert(' path = ' + f.name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i got the files = document.getElementById('files'); and remaining is your code doesn't do any thing no errors no log as well.

Comment: Here is the entire code with console log aswell as alert            function getFileNames()
{
 var files = document.getElementById("files").files;

 for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++)
 {
        console.log(' path = ' + f.name);
        alert(' path = ' + f.name);

    }
}

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
var path = $('#files').val();
```

loop through the array, use

```
var names = "";
var path = $('#files').each(function(i, el) {
    names = names + el.val() + ",";
});
```

Comment: Thanks but i am getting this error in firefox. el.val is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

names = names + el.val() + ",";

Comment: Use `$(el).val()` instead of `el.val()`

Comment: it only returns one file name though

Comment: What "array"? #files is an id selector, there is only going to be a single element in the jQuery object