# Display file input names on screen

Tags: jquery, forms, html-input

I have code that allows users to upload files. I don't know how many files there will be.

I would like to print the names of the files on screen.

The following script just prints "file[]".

What do i need to change?

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the standard form submission, as you're using 

    var $form = $(this);
    var act = 'add';

    //Get elements
    var fields = $form.find('.file-field');

    for (var i = 0; i <= fields.length; i++) {
        //get element using .eq()
        var el = fields.eq(i);

        //Read name property
         alert(el.prop('name'));
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type='file' name='file[]' class=' form-control file-field multi' maxlength='2' accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif"  id="uploadFile0"/>
  <button class="btn btn-primary submit" >SEND</button>
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get file names from input type file in html 5 using javascript or jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982252/how-to-get-file-names-from-input-type-file-in-html-5-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: @PaulRoub - I'll try. thanks